# How to create mutable AND immutable copy of object in JS

Tags: javascript

Without using any additional libraries, how I can I create an immutable copy of an object and retain a mutable copy.

```
var mutableCopy = immutableData;

Object.freeze(immutableData);

mutableCopy.newProp = 'mutated!';

console.log(mutableCopy.hasOwnProperty('newProp')); // false
```

It seems that `Object.freeze()` also freezes objects by reference.

**How can I create a mutable and immutable copy of an object?**

Comment: Is this a deeply nested object, or is it only one level deep regarding the properties?

Comment: nested 2 levels deep, but I only want to mutate properties in the first level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var objCopy = {};

for ( var propKey in objToClone )
    objCopy[ propKey ] = objToClone[ propKey ];
```

And object.freeze whichever you prefer. If you've a more complex/deeper object and need to mutate those deeper properties, I'd probably just use something hacky like

```
var objCopy = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( objToClone ) );
```

Comment: JSON.deserialize/serialize? Do you mean JSON.parse/stringify?

Comment: I tried `var objCopy = Object.create(objToClone);` which I found on another SO question which didn't work for copying the package.json file by reference, but the JSON stringify and then parse worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are slightly right in this is a problem of pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value. In reality, the pass-by-reference occurs in the first line. Both `mutableCopy` and `immutableData` point to the same object on the JS heap.

What you should do is make a new object that is a duplicate of the old one. Then, freezing the new object will leave the old one as a mutable copy while preventing modifications.

```
var newObj = {}
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
}

Object.freeze(newObj);
```

You can, of course, make the new object the mutable copy and the old one the immutable one should you so choose.

Comment: Even without the `Object.freeze` I could modify the properties of `newObj` here, and the properties of `obj` still wouldn't change, right?

Comment: Looks like I wouldn't need to use `Object.freeze`

Comment: You are correct. If you modify either `obj` or `newObj` after copying, the other will not change.